# is GP10 still a viable choice as support?

Tags: league-of-legends

With Season 3 here, lots of new items have been release. One in particular is the Sightstone, and if you didnt know this item allows you to **basically** have unlimited wards and a decent amount of health with an upfront purchase. My previous reasoning for GP10 was to make up for the lose of gold from purchasing tons of wards and having no serious income besides assists and the occasional minion/champion kill. Season 3 also upgraded the amount of gold you get over time, combine that with 3 quint GP10 ruins and masteries in GP10 your making a decent amount of gold.

**So, would it be viable to change my build completely away from GP10 and rely on assists?** I use Leona, Taric, Blitzcrank, or Alistar when I support (i have others but they are the best in my opinion). Although I havent gone back to Ranked since I started to mainly support, lots of assists are pretty easy to come by. My current build focuses half and half. Runes/Masteries have a focus around GP10 and survivability, while my item build focuses on damage and survivability.

Comment: regardless on whether or not you get gp10 items, definitely get rid of the runes in favor of cdr and armor/mr/hp. Much more useful as support imo

Comment: i only use gp10 quints. glyphs are health, seals are Mana regen, marks are health. tanking for you adc is essential. but yes i was definately thinking about changing my quints to something more usable

Comment: Note also the impact of the pickpocket mastery on support chars: you can now earn money from harassing enemy champs. Granted, it's not as much as gp10, but it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You list primarily tanky supports, who were hit the hardest with the removal of Heart of Gold.  This leaves two other GP/10 items: Philosopher's Stone and Kage's Lucky Pick.  *I ignored Avarice Blade as I don't feel it compliments the support role.*

A Philo stone can build into Shurelya's Reverie, Eleisa's Miracle, or Ohmwrecker.  Shurelya's is still a great support item, and Eleisa's reduces the cooldowns of the summoner spells Heal, Clarity, and Clairvoyance.  It can also free an inventory spot if purchased early enough! Ohmwrecker is outshined by both items, and I don't recommend buying it on a support.

Kage's Lucky Pick turns into Shard of True Ice, Twin Shadows, Morellonomicon, or Will of the Ancients.  The first two are most viable on a support, and the Shard continues to provide GP/10.

So a lot of things affect whether GP/10 is still viable.

For a Philo Stone:

- Did you take Heal or Clairvoyance?
- Do you need extra sustain?
- Does your team need a Shurelya's?  Is anyone else buying one?

For Kage's Lucky Pick:

- Does your champion benefit from extra AP?
- Do you need additional CC?

Another new item is the Sightstone.  For an investment of 950 gold, you can place up to 2 wards at a time, with each ward lasting 3 minutes.  The Sightstone holds 4 wards total and refills when you return to base.  This breaks down to 50 gold/minute, and starts saving money after 19 minutes (assuming you immediately place wards when available).  It also provides +180 health, making it a strong choice for tanky supports.

Previously, GP/10 items were essential to compensate for the cost of wards.  This is largely mitigated with the usage of a Sightstone, freeing money for other items.

A Philosopher's Stone costs 700 gold and pays for itself in 23.33 minutes.  Kage's Lucky Pick costs 765 and pays for itself in 25.5 minutes.  These times are halved if you sell the item.  Because it takes so long to make money from GP/10 items, it's best to buy them as early as possible.

Compare this to the gold granted from kills/assists.  A champion who hasn't been killed is worth 300 gold, and 50% of that for an assist.  The more times a champion is killed, the less money the kill rewards, with a minimum of 15 gold.

Since 2 GP/10 items provide 60 gold/minute, you have to get a 150 gold assist every 2.5 minutes for assists to equal GP/10 items.  You can get an additional 5 GP/10 from Quints and masteries, resulting in 90 gold/minute and needing an assist every 1.66 minutes.

The new pick-pocket mastery offers an additional avenue to generate gold.  Unfortunately, this isn't very viable on melee supports.

While supports are no longer required to get GP/10 items to support expensive ward-buying habits, these GP/10 items are still cost-efficient for longer games AND they upgrade into items that are very useful for most supports.

Ultimately, the decision to buy GP/10 items comes down to play-style and preferences.  If you prefer to play aggressively and need extra stats to stay alive, skip GP items.  If you're trying to maximize gold gained, GP/10 is still the better choice (unless you can get an assist every 1.6 minutes!).

**tl;dr**: GP/10 is still very viable, especially since those items build into new support-focused items.  However, it's no longer a necessity since the Sightstone makes warding much cheaper.

Comment: I would say even with the removal of Heart of Gold and the addition of Sight Stone, tanky supports are buffed. Great answer though, I seriously need to scroll through all these new items.

Comment: Morellonomicon is also viable on ranged mage support champs, like Lulu. Especially that they removed the active to make something activated by basic attacks, making it much more natural to cast, and adding a point to your regular attacks.

Comment: Good point, I missed the change from active to passive on it.

Comment: You could get an assist every 1.6 minutes (or 2.5) AND get the GP10 gold and be really rich.  Really for not getting GP10 to be worth it you have to get an additional assist every 2.5 minutes that you wouldn't have gotten without whatever items you bought (which seems even less likely).

Comment: Note that Sightstone is now more expensive, as of the last updates (950 instead of 700). It's still helping supports a lot, but is now coming a bit later in the game.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is still a great help to any support. Philo still builds into useful things, it's nerfed in stats but the GP10 is the same. On the other hand Kage's lucky pick got nerfed in GP10 but now it builds into shard of true ice which keeps the GP10 at the end of it's build and has a useful slow active. It is still viable to buy GP10 perhaps even more so now because there are more support items.

On the other hand going no GP10 and all assists is actually more viable because of the new sight stones. However to go without GP10 is very risky. By building with a larger focus on kills and assists and less on a safe gold setup, you essentially force yourself to either get kills and assists or significantly reduce the effectiveness of your ward control if you fail. The sight stone is not capable of warding the entire map. Only your lane, so you still need to buy wards and you need to buy oracles/pink wards as well.

Put more simply: It's snowball or bust without GP10

Comment: good answer, I was definately thinking that in ranked games lack of gp10 would punish me more then normals. still might try it

Comment: although i disagree its completely the supports job to ward the entire map. at the very least jungle should be carrying some of that responisibility. when i ADC or Mid i usually buy a ward or two if i got gold remaining after an item purchase

Comment: @Paralytic I agree during lane it's not the supports job to ward the entire map but late game the support needs to ward the map and buy oracles to counter enemy wards.

Answer (score 2):

I think support as a whole will gravitate towards winning the lane as opposed to wait until the gold items kick in.

Sightstone is by far the best gold item right now (saves you up to 350 gold every time you shop), and you can't buy it at the start, so you have room to explore there. I like to start 0/13/17 cloth+ward(s)+pots, and go crazy aggressive with my trading advantage. By level 3, I can zone pretty much anyone.

I feel Philo stone is simply not worth it anymore with the health regen nerf and Flask, and Kage's also doesn't give you the stats you need on tanky all-in supports. The loss in gold is mitigated by Pickpocket, the ambient gold increase, and gold quints. And assists, of course.

Philo stone and Kage are more snowbally items at this point, I think. Get them when you have the advantage, but don't sacrifice your usefulness for them.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just as viable as before.

I'm going to look at this purely from a cash perspective.  Most supports are built around the idea that you don't need many items to be effective (for example Taric's stun stuns the same even if you're naked) so you can get away with having weak GP10 items in your inventory for a long time.

If you can pick up Philo Stone and Lucky Pick in the first 10-12 minutes, you will have a lot of extra cash to buy any other items you might want on your champ.  Like Toast said, though, it also depends on whether you can use the items they build into.  If you don't want those items then it might not be worth it.