# In what situation would you buy gp10's?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there a particularly good time to buy gp10 items?

Is it more useful to buy them early and sell them later for a potential profit, and how long do you need the gp10 to actually make a profit from it? Because it takes awhile for them to be profitable, is buying them later in the game a bad idea?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=gp10 should provide you with some ideas for gp10 its been brought up a decent amount on Arqade

Comment: I really don't like the way this question is stated, as it is too general. The cases where you buy gp10 on a ap champion are different than when you buy them on an adc champion and are different than when you buy them on a support champion.  So far the answers have shown this same problem as they're all lackluster attempts to be general as well.  Its probably too late to refine the question but just saying, if you want concise answers to improve your gameplay, ask a concise question :P

Comment: Philo stone takes 23 min 20 seconds to pay for itself.
Kage's Lucky Pick takes 32 min.
Avarice Blade takes 44 min 24 seconds, however every kill gives you an additional 2 gold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: This is why it's important to have GP/10 on support]

As mentioned in comments, [avarice blade](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Avarice_Blade) on trynd, GP, Nocturne, or even Garen can work.  Other than that, it's quite a niche item and isn't very cost-effective for other champs.  They took out **HoG**, which was the only GP/10 item that worked well on EVERY champ :( .  [Philo stone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Philosopher's_Stone) works well on most tops that use mana, as well as EVERY support.  As mentioned before, if you are planning on upgrading to either [morelonomicon](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Morellonomicon) or [DFG](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Deathfire_Grasp), [Kage's lucky pick](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kage's_Lucky_Pick) is worthwhile to get early on your AP Carry.  (edit: just noticed it's part of athene's unholy grail while i was playing a match with Galio, good pick up for him, as well.)

Support should ALWAYS have a philo, as later game every support should have [shurelya's](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shurelya's_Reverie).

It should be noted that GP/10 isn't common on jungler, with the exception of mana hungry ones, like Amumumu or Maokai, which benefit greatly from Philo, and then even moreso from Shurelya's later game.

SK gaming did a great write up on GP/10s [here](http://www.sk-gaming.com/content/53972-In_depth_GP10_Study_for_AP_Carries__Graphs_Tables_and_Video).

***As for specific questions in the OP***:  Good time is earliest possible, I.E. I rush them before boots when i'm support.   Later game they are generally a waste of inventory slot.  Selling them isn't as cost effective as upgrading them to something relevant for your champion.  Only time i would sell them is if I went something like 2 philo stones, upgrade one to shurelyas, sell the second one to get something else...

Comment: I don't think I ever have used the active on Shurelya's Reverie though I buy it whenever I play support.

Comment: @ZackT. It's so easy to do so, same with randuins, SOTD, Youmuu's, etc...  The way I got better at remembering to use actives = Play DOTA2.  Almost every item has an active, so you are forced to learn to remember them.  Give it a try! :)

Answer (score 6):

I love gp10 items. The best 4 situations where you need buy gp10 are:

1. **You are a Support**. You must let your carry last hit all minions in your lane, and you need the extra income to help support.
2. **You are far behind in your lane or in the game**. If your lane opponent is denying your farming by zoning you out, you will need some gp10.
3. **You are a bad farmer**. While you are learning to farm better, stick with gp10!
4. **You plan buy an upgrade to a gp10 item later in the game anyway**, like Morellonomicon, etc.

Good Luck!

Comment: I've actually been picking up an early Avarice Blade as an AD carry. I find that the passive (increased income on kill) is very helpful and it builds into a Statikk Shiv, which is *very* useful on certain AD carries.

Comment: I like to go a gp10 on top ad's aswell, gives extra income that can always help.

Comment: I would add a very particular case: If you somehow benefit from critical and you're a good farmer get Avarice Blade for sure. 
Perfect examples are Gangplank and Tryndamere. They both can rush avarice and make the fullest of it's passive without losing much strength. Cause I think most ad carries would rather get other early items...

Comment: More details on gp10 on a support: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95276/is-gp10-still-a-viable-choice-as-support.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some key points to have in mind:

- Things changed a bit in Season 3, especially for supports (see [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95276/is-gp10-still-a-viable-choice-as-support) for more details). GP10 is less important, as supporting becomes cheaper, thanks to items like [Crystalline Flask](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Crystalline_Flask) (to keep you in shape) or [Sightstone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sightstone) (to ward around) which you have to buy only once, instead of during the whole game.
- Remember also that such items take time to pay for themselves. It takes more than 20 minutes for any GP10 item to pay for itself, only after it brings you gold to spend on other items. So get them early.
- GP10 items bring you back only 50% of the cost (as opposed to 70% for other items) when you sell them, so they are not really a good "investment" if you don't plan on keeping them.
- The main rule (in my opinion) is that you should only get GP10 items which influence you directly, and almost only if you can upgrade them into an item which is useful to you.

Comment: I disagree with your first point.  A support without GP10s is about as useful as a hole in a boat.

Comment: and Flask on a support? Really? what a waste.... :(

Comment: @Marco - I haven't said to not buy any GP10. Just that it's less important. Sightstone saves you 300 gold per shop visit, for example. But for sure, supports shouldn't focus on buying almost any gp10 item, like before with a typical philo+HoG+kage on most supports. Instead, they should take only items which they can directly profit from.

Comment: About the flask, I don't see it as a waste at all for an aggressive support like Lulu. You will need extra mana, and frequent healing to compensate for the hits you take instead of your carry.

Comment: I guess we just play support differently :/

Comment: I would like to add tho that your point 2 and 3 might not be so bad after all. Because this would mean if you keep your GP10 for 10minutes or more and then sell it you would have profit.